# Union of function pointers

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that has different member function signatures. Based upon some requirement (to optimize execution time specifically) I need to call one the above methods at a specific time. I have plan to create a structure of below type:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
   public:
      void Show() {std::cout << "Called 0" << std::flush << std::endl;}
      int Show1() {std::cout << "Called 1" << std::flush << std::endl;}
      double Show2(char z) {std::cout << "Called 2" << std::flush << std::endl;}
      float Show3(int op, float x) {std::cout << "Called 3" << std::flush << std::endl;}
};

struct details
{
   int type ; /* methods to be called resp : 0 =Show,1=Show1,2=Show2,3=Show3*/
   union 
   {
      void (A::*fn)();
      int (A::*fn1)();
      double (A::*fn2)(char z);
      float (A::*fn3)(int op, float x);
   }fnptr;
};

int main()
{
   struct details d1 [4] ;
   d1[0].type = 0;
   d1[0].fnptr.fn = &A::Show;
   A a1;
   (a1.*(d1[0].fnptr.fn))();
   d1[0].type = 1;
   d1[0].fnptr.fn1 = &A::Show1;
   (a1.*(d1[0].fnptr.fn1))();
   d1[0].type = 1;
   d1[0].fnptr.fn2 = &A::Show2;
   (a1.*(d1[0].fnptr.fn2))('a');
   d1[0].type = 4;
   d1[0].fnptr.fn3 = &A::Show3;
   (a1.*(d1[0].fnptr.fn3))(2,3.14);
}


MINGW64 /c/work
$ c++ try.cpp -std=c++11

MINGW64 /c/work
$ ./a.exe
Called 0
Called 1
Called 2
Called 3
```

However I am not able to initialize the array :

```
struct details d1 [4] = {{0, &A::Show}, {1, &A::Show1}, {2, &A::Show2}, {3, &A::Show3}};
```

It states compilation error

```
int main()
{
struct details d1 [4] = {{0, &A::Show}, {1, &A::Show1}, {2, &A::Show2}, {3, &A::Show3}};
}

try.cpp: In function 'int main()':
try.cpp:26:87: error: cannot convert 'int (A::*)()' to 'void (A::*)()' in initialization
 struct details d1 [4] = {{0, &A::Show}, {1, &A::Show1}, {2, &A::Show2}, {3, &A::Show3}};
                                                                                       ^
try.cpp:26:87: error: cannot convert 'double (A::*)(char)' to 'void (A::*)()' in initialization
try.cpp:26:87: error: cannot convert 'float (A::*)(int, float)' to 'void (A::*)()' in initialization
```

How can I initialize the structure properly?

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Comment: [OT] *`<< std::flush << std::endl;`*: `std::endl` already flushes.

Comment: a union of function pointers, performance and with tag dispatching... sounds not as a solution! And a tagged union is already availabl: std::variant. And tag dispatching is also available: std::visit. If you have no c++17 compiler, you can use the boost versions of the features

Comment: why cant, whoever picks the right member of the union, simply call the right method directly? On the other hand at the place where you eventually call the method you need to know what parameters to pass. In your example, in main you know what are the params and can pass them, but then you didnt need the union. I have the feeling that this is a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @user463035818 - The called method is intended to be a call back or for a later point of time - the overall intention is to iterate the struct and call each method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> However I am not able to initialize the array :
>
> ```
> struct details d1 [4] = {{0, &A::Show}, {1, &A::Show1}, {2, &A::Show2}, {3, &A::Show3}};
> ```

When a `union` is initialized using that syntax, the value must correspond to its first member. In your case, the first member is `fn`, whose type is `void (A::*)()`.

That line is equivalent to:

```
 struct details d1 [4] = {{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}};
 d1[0].fn = &A::Show;
 d1[1].fn = &A::Show1;
 d1[2].fn = &A::Show2;
 d1[3].fn = &A::Show3;
```

That explains the compiler error.

[Documentation from the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.init.aggr#15):

> When a union is initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer, the braces shall only contain an initializer-clause for the first non-static data member of the union. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> union u { int a; const char* b; };
> u a = { 1 };
> u b = a;
> u c = 1;                        // error
> u d = { 0, "asdf" };            // error
> u e = { "asdf" };               // error
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Comment: My understanding is that all union members have the same address.

Comment: @PeterWilson, why is that relevant in this context?

Answer (score 4):

Currently, in C++, when a union is [*aggregate initialized*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), only the first *non-static data member* (can be, or) is initialized. you cannot work around that.

Good news is that, from [**C++20**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers), you'll be able to [select an active member during *aggregate initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers). So, this syntax should work in few years time. :-)

```
details d1 [4] = {{0, {.fn = &A::Show}}, {1, {.fn1 = &A::Show1}}, {2, { .fn2 = &A::Show2}}, {3, { .fn3 = &A::Show3}}};
```

Comment: This syntax already works for a long time, as long as you don't disable c99 extension.

Comment: @liliscent, yes, some compilers have always supported it as an **extension** to ISO-C++ specifications;